# Delete word with a match but keep the original word as such in the file

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am trying to achieve the following:

There is a file which has multiple words say for example:

Output of sample txt is

```
testStr
testmystring
testmystring_1
testmystringwq
testStr_3
testStrasd
testStr-345
testStr1
testingStr1
```

Now what I am trying to achieve is that if I operate on the file line by line i.e. using testStr the first  time then all the words which start from testStr should get removed but here testStr should remain i.e.

Expected output is

```
testStr
testmystring
testmystring_1
testmystringwq
testingStr1
```

Now the next string from file should be compared i.e. testmystring. Then the expected output is

```
testStr
testmystring
testingStr1
```

And so on...

I tried using the sed command for deletion using pattern and it works. But I need the original pattern to remain in the file.

```
sed -i '/testStr*/d' ./sample txt
```

Comment: My file is sorted but I think I might haven't been clear in my question.

Comment: What I mean is this file is a huge file and I need to read it line by line and do the similar operation.. please let me know if the question is clear

Comment: I have edited the original question

Comment: I think you meant to write `.` where you have `*`.

Comment: You always talk about "string"s in your question but then you accepted a solution which operates on regexps, not strings. So, for example if your input file contained `dr. who` and `drake` and your list of strings to be removed contained `dr.` then both of those lines would be deleted instead of just `dr. who`. Is that really what you want? Or are you just hoping that no RE metachars will be present?

Comment: Thanks Ed for the reply.... So my original search string will always be from within the file itself and not provided explicitly by the user.. so as per your question if there were entries like dr. who and drake, so the first match should be with dr. who and second shall be with drake. Having said this I will definitely try your suggestions and get back to you early next week.. thanks again for your valuable time and support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this?

```
$ grep -Evf <(sed 's/^/^/; s/$/.+/' sample.txt) sample.txt
testStr
testmystring
testingStr1
```

(Requires bash, zsh, ksh93 or another shell that understands `<(command)` style redirection.)

Comment: You don't need to add the `+` in the sed and so you don't need the `-E` in the grep. The whole sed command could just be `'s/.*/^&./'`

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\<\(testStr\)\S*/\1/;H;$!d;x;s/.//;:a;s/\<\(\(testStr\n\).*\)\2/\1/;ta' file
```

Remove all characters following the string `testStr`. Store the results and unchanged lines in the hold space. At the end of the file, remove the introduced newline and then remove all but the first occurrence of the string `testStr`.

N.B. A simpler solution might be:

```
sed 's/\<\(testStr\)\S*/\1/' file | sort -u
```

However this will remove duplicates of lines other than just `testStr` and may also change the original order.

EDIT: To accommodate the changes to the original question, two files are provided. The first original file contains strings to be tested against (file) and a new second file containing only those strings (fileInput) to be matched.

Using the above solution and alternation, build a script from the fileInput:

```
sed 'H;$!d;x;s/.//;s/\n/|/g;s#.*#s/\\<(&)\\S*/\\1/;H;$!d;x;s/.//;:a;s/\\<(((&)\\n).*)\\2/\\1/;ta#' fileInput |
sed -Ef - file
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do what you asked for with literal strings:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{tgts[$0]; next} {for (tgt in tgts) if (($0 != tgt) && (index($0,tgt) == 1)) next} 1' targets file
testStr
testmystring
testingStr1
```

The above was run on these input files:

```
$ tail -n +0 targets file
==> targets <==
testStr
testmystring

==> file <==
testStr
testmystring
testmystring_1
testmystringwq
testStr_3
testStrasd
testStr-345
testStr1
testingStr1
```

The above will work no matter what characters are in either file.